# Separating two datetime values from a single string

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

I need to write a method to take in a string containing two datetime values, and separate out the values. These datetime values can be in any valid ISO-8601 format which means I can't just split on a character index. The values will be separated by a hyphen which also means I can't just use str.split() either.

I've written this function using some Reg-Ex, but the client has asked me to use python-dateutil instead.

```py
def split_range(times):
    regex = re.compile("[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{2}([T]([0-9]{2}:?){2,3}(\.[0-9]{3})?)?Z?")
    split_times = regex.finditer(times)
    final_times = []

    for time in split_times:

        time = time.group(0)

        datetime_value = datetime.fromisoformat(time)
        final_times.append(datetime_value.isoformat())

    return final_times
```

This function should take in a string like this:
*(these are all the strings I use in my tests)*

`20080809-20080815`

`2008-08-08-2008-08-09`

`2008-08-08T17:21-2008-08-09T17:31`

`2008-08-08T17:21-2008-08-09T17:31`

`2008-08-08T17:21:000-2008-08-09T17:31:000`

`2008-08-08T17:21:000-2008-08-09T17:310:00`

`2008-08-08T17:21:000.000-2008-08-09T17:31:000.000`

and split it into two separate values

ex. `2019-08-08` & `2019-08-09`

The client doesn't really like the use of regex here, and would like me to replace it with using dateutil, but I haven't seen anything that seems like it would do what I need. Is there a dateutil method I can use to accomplish this, and if not, is there another library that does have something?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the timestamps will be of equal length? For example, is it ever possible the first value could be just a date but the second value will be date+time?

Comment: if the argument-string always looks like that, why dont you just split it in two halfs by slicing?

Comment: @Doflaminhgo It won't always look like that exact one. AFAIK each half could be any supported ISO 8601 format

Comment: As a side note, you should add some ISO8601 strings like `2019-09-08T00:00-1700` into your test suite. It is the one of the formats most likely to cause ambiguities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best thing to do might be to ask your client to change the delimiter from `-` to something else like a space or a tab or something that will not show up in an ISO 8601 string and split on that, but if you must use `-` as a delimiter *and* you must support any valid ISO 8601 string, your best option is to try and look for the pattern `-(--|\d{4})`, since all valid ISO 8601 datetimes will either start with 4 digits or they will start with `--`. If you find a dash followed by 4 digits, you have either found a negative time zone or the beginning of your next ISO 8601 datetime.

Additionally, there are no valid ISO 8601 datetime formats that contain `\d{4}-\d{4}` and if you find a `-(\d{4})` that represents a time zone offset, it is necessarily at the *end* of your first ISO 8601 string, so it is sufficient to use a negative lookahead to ensure that the pattern is not repeated, so, putting it all together:

```
import re
from dateutil.parser import isoparse


def parse_iso8601_pairs(isostr):
    # In a string containing two ISO 8601 strings delimited by -, the substring
    # "-\d{4}" is only found at the beginning of the second datetime or the
    # end of *either* datetime. If it is found at the end of the first datetime,
    # it will always be followed by `-\d{4}`, so we can use negative lookahead
    # to find the beginning of the next string.
    #
    # Note: ISO 8601 datetimes can also begin with `--`, but parsing these is
    # not supported yet in dateutil.parser.isoparse, as of verison 2.8.0. The
    # regex includes this type of string in order to make at least the splitting
    # method work even if the parsing method doesn't support "missing year"
    # ISO 8601 strings.
    m = re.search(r"-(--|\d{4})(?!-(--|\d{4}))", isostr)
    dt1 = None
    dt2 = None

    if m is None:
        raise ValueError(f"String does not contain two ISO 8601 datetimes " +
                         "delimited by -: {isostr}")

    split_on = m.span()[0]
    str1 = isostr[0:split_on]
    str2 = isostr[split_on + 1:]

    # You may want to wrap the error handling here with a nicer message
    dt1 = isoparse(str1)
    dt2 = isoparse(str2)

    return dt1, dt2
```

As far as I know this will work for any pair of ISO 8601-compliant strings delimited by `-` *except* the obscure "year missing" format: `--MM-?DD`. The splitting portion of the code will work even in the face of strings like `--04-01`, but [`dateutil.parser.isoparse`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse) does not currently support that format, so the parse will fail. Perhaps more problematic is the fact that `--MMDD` is *also* a valid ISO8601 format, and that will match `-\d{4}` and give an erroneous split. If you want to support that format and you have a modified parser that can handle `--MMDD`, I believe you can make a more complicated regex that handles the `--MMDD` case (and if someone wants to do this I'll be happy to edit it into the article), or you can simply "guess and check" by iterating over matches using `re.finditer` until you find a place to split your string that yields a valid ISO 8601 datetime on both sides of the delimiter.

**Note**: This method will also work if you substitute in `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat` for `dateutil.parser.isoparse`. The difference is that `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat` parses strings that are mostly a subset of what `dateutil.parser.isoparse` handles - it is the *inverse* of `datetime.datetime.isoformat` and will parse anything that could be created by calling the `isoformat` method on a datetime object, wherease `isoparse` is intended to parse anything that is a valid ISO 8601 string. If you know that your datetimes were produced by calling the `isoformat()` method, then `fromisoformat` is the better choice of ISO 8601 parser.

Comment: But either way, I'll still need to use regex logic, right?

Comment: You need to detect where the delimiter is in *some* way. This regex makes things easier, but theoretically you could just iterate over every `-` and see if splitting the string on it and calling `dateutil.parser.isoparse` on either side of the delimiter just works. That is an unnecessarily slow way to do things, though.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything

Answer (score 0):

use `re.findall()`

```
import re

text = "2019-08-03-2019-08-09"
match = re.findall(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', text)

print (match)
```

output:

```
['2019-08-03', '2019-08-09']
```

example:

```
import re

text = "2019-08-03-2019-08-09xxxxxThis is test xxxxx---2017-01-01"
match = re.findall(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', text)

print (match)
```

output:

```
['2019-08-03', '2019-08-09', '2017-01-01']
```